# Do Until with Get-SmbOpenFile

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-5.0

I'm trying to check if any files are opened on a server with powershell. 
I've got the below script which kind of works

If I start it when there are no files opened it checks first, waits 10 seconds and then prints the message "No files are opened". If I open any files and start the script it says "Files are opened, please wait..." but when I close all files and disconnect all sessions it still says the same

```
Clear-Host
$CheckOpenfiles = Get-SmbOpenFile
Do
    {
     "$(get-date) Files are opened, please wait..."
     Start-Sleep 10
     } Until (!$CheckOpenfiles) 
     "No files are opened"
```

Comment: Checking the once assigned value repeatedly doesn't change the initial state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As LotPings notes in the comments, you assign your value to `$CheckOpenfiles` before you start looping. This means that it is not reevaluated in your Until conditional.

```
Do {
    "$(get-date) Files are opened, please wait..."
    Start-Sleep 10
} Until (!(Get-SmbOpenFile)) 
"No files are opened"
```